# Data is missing from HDFS while transfering compressed files using Flume

Tags: hadoop, flume, hadoop2, flume-ng

I  am trying to transfer zip/compressed files to HDFS using flume but i observe only few of files are getting transferred. e.g. 3 out of 12 files only.
I tried many times to check if random files are getting transferred but every time same files are getting transferred.e.g. 3,7,11 and 12 file.
My zip files are on the same machine where hadoop is installed.

Details :

spool.conf

---

```
#Agent components
a1.sources = src1
a1.channels = chan1
a1.sinks = sink1

#configuring the souce
a1.sources.src1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.src1.spoolDir = /home/hdeveloper/Logs
a1.sources.src1.deserializer=org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobDeserializer$Builder


#configuring the channel
a1.channels.chan1.type = file

#Checkpoint directory
a1.channels.chan1.checkpointDir = /home/hdeveloper/flume-metadata/.flume/file-channel/checkpoint

#log files created in Data directory while running flume-agent
a1.channels.chan1.dataDirs = /home/hdeveloper/flume-metadata/.flume/file-channel/data


#configuring the Sink
a1.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/twitterdata
a1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
a1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = CompressedStream
a1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.codeC = GzipCodec

a1.sources.src1.channels = chan1
a1.sinks.sink1.channel = chan1


------------------------------------------------

command to execute :

[hdeveloper@localhost apache-flume-1.6.0-bin]$ bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf --conf-file ./conf/spool.conf --name a1 -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

---

I don't see any error in logs